# Why the state is not changed

Tags: javascript, react-native, use-state

I have the following function, and there is two Alerts. The first Alert shows that the `settingsChangedRoute` is `true`, so after `setSettingsChanged(settingsChangedRoute)`; the `settingsChanged` value should be true too, as I understand it. But it is false and I don't get why. Please help to fix it, as it should be `true`.

```
const [settingsChanged, setSettingsChanged] = useState(false);
//...
const load = async () => {
    if (!!(route?.params)) {
      const settingsChangedRoute = route.params.settingsChanged;
      Alert.alert(`settingsChangedRoute === ${settingsChangedRoute}`);
      setSettingsChanged(settingsChangedRoute);
    }
    const savedMode = await AsyncStorage.getItem('mode');
    if (!!savedMode) {
      const savedBlocked = await AsyncStorage.getItem('blocked');
      if (savedBlocked) {
        setBlocked(JSON.parse(savedBlocked));
      }
      setMode(savedMode);
      const savedTurn = await AsyncStorage.getItem('turn');
      setTurn(savedTurn);
      const savedFieldSize = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fieldSize');
      const parcedFieldSize = JSON.parse(savedFieldSize);
      setFieldSize(parcedFieldSize);
      const savedDifficulty = await AsyncStorage.getItem('difficulty');
      setDifficulty(savedDifficulty);
      Alert.alert(`settingsChanged === ${settingsChanged}`);
      if (settingsChanged) {
        setInitialFieldState();
        setSettingsChanged(false);
      } else {
        const fieldStateJSON = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fieldState');
        if (!!fieldStateJSON) {
          setFieldState(JSON.parse(fieldStateJSON));
        }
      }
    } else {
      setInitialFieldState();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **useState()** hook updates values asynchronously. So, even though you updated **settingsChanged** to true by the time the code execution reached to the second alert, the values are not changed yet. It is, therefore, advised to use **useEffect** hook.

Refer to this doc:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```
useEffect(()=>{
   // write code that will execute after settingsChanged has been updated
},[settingsChanged])
```

If you need to just execute a code only when **settingsChanged** value is updated to true, you can simply add a condition inside useEffect

```
useEffect(()=>{
   if(settingsChanged) {
            // write code that will execute after settingsChanged has been 
            // updated to true
   }
},[settingsChanged])
```